# Which ranking system is best for time-based competitions (e.g. Rally car racing)

Tags: statistics, algorithms

Let's suppose I have a database of 1000 competitors and 100 events.  Each event has anything from 150 to 300 entrants.

The sport (e.g. rally car racing) is a simple against-the-clock event.  Participants set off at regular intervals, and the race is decided by finishing times.

I assume there's already established algorithms for ranking competitors under these circumstances.  Where should I be looking?

I've read up about Elo and TrueSkill, but it seems both are much more about 1-on-1 competition, or group-on-group, and not many-on-many.  While they could maybe be adapted I'm not quite sure how to go about it, and I'm also unsure if they're suitable at all in this case.

I tried adapting Elo to change a competition of many people into hundreds of 1-on-1 matches, but you end up with the problem of a winner "running away" with a huge lead.  Maybe with some tweaking of various factors it could work, but I feel I'm probably barking up the wrong tree?

Many thanks

Comment: If you ask for the best, you need to specify what you're trying to minimize or maximize.

Comment: Fair point.  I'm not sure I fully know that myself yet.  Would you be able to point me towards possibilities other than Elo/TrueSkill, so I can educate myself more on the subject?

Comment: You have misunderstood TrueSkill. It most certainly is designed for many-on-many modelling. If in your cursory reading of it you concluded it is group-on-group it may be a simple misunderstanding in that TrueSkill is for generic use and models n teams with m_i members in team i, where n and the m_i are not limited or constrained, and your many-on-many scenario is simply the case where all the m_i are 1 (teams all have on member). TrueSkill models this admirably.